# Sum of a column in snowflake

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have two calculated columns with case statements. Now, I need to take Sum of those columns and need the difference in it.

For Ex.

Select Case when account = '30' and status='active' then value as value1,
case when account = '31' and status='active' then value as value2,
Sum(value1) - Sum(Value2) as Total_SUM
from table

How can we achieve this.. This gives me a missing group by clause error. I tried many things but did not work out.

Answer (score 0):

Use conditional aggregation and sum the `CASE` expressions:

```sql
SELECT
    SUM(CASE WHEN account = '30' THEN value ELSE 0 END) AS value1,
    SUM(CASE WHEN account = '31' THEN value ELSE 0 END) AS value2,
    SUM(CASE WHEN account = '30' THEN value ELSE 0 END) -
        SUM(CASE WHEN account = '31' THEN value ELSE 0 END) AS Total_SUM
FROM yourTable
WHERE status = 'active';
```

Comment: with your first 2 sum statements you are summing all the values of value1. I want the value separate record-level values and then the sum of it and then I will have to have the difference.